# Why Task.CurrentId becomes NULL after Task.Delay?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0

I'm using `C#` with `.NET 7` and testing some `Task` related things. I've noticed that `Task.CurrentID` becomes `Null` after `await Task.Delay(1000);`. But if I use `Thread.Sleep()` then it doesn't become null. I'm not understanding why?

**My understanding**: I know `Task.Delay()` returns a new `Task` and applying `await` on that will suspend further execution. When the delay is over, control will move to the next line and on that line, I have `Console.WriteLine("Task ID# " + Task.CurrentId);` this statement should have `Task.CurrentId` value because control is returned to the calling task again... or I'm getting this wrong?

```
internal class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
   
        await Task.Run( SomeMethod);

        /*var tsk =  Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await SomeMethod());
        await tsk.Result;*/

        Console.WriteLine("======END======");
        Console.Read();
    }

    static async Task SomeMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task ID# " + Task.CurrentId);
        Console.WriteLine("Thread ID# " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine("Is Thread Pool?# " + Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);
        
        Console.WriteLine("======Loop started======");

        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            //Thread.Sleep(1000);  if i use this then Task.CurrentId is not null

            Console.WriteLine("Task ID# " + Task.CurrentId);
            Console.WriteLine("Thread ID# " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Console.WriteLine("Is Thread Pool?# " + Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Task result image]

**With Thread.Sleep():**

[image: With Thread.Sleep()]

Comment: Tasks aren’t threads

Comment: Why `await Task.Run( SomeMethod);` and not `await SomeMethod()`?

Comment: @DanielA.White Well yes, i understand that. but `await Task.Delay(1000);` must wait and then execute next line ..??

Comment: @gunr2171 this is for testing purposes only. I'm testing Task.Run() and Task.Factory.StartNew()... etc

Comment: @RaoArman tasks aren't threads and the ID doesn't matter. A Task is a *Promise* that something may complete in the Future. It may or may *not* run on a thread. It may not run at all, it may only represent some other asynchronous operation. `await` doesn't return you to the original thread, especially in web and console applications.

Comment: It's only in Desktop applications that `await` returns to the UI thread, to allow people to update the UI from the only place they can, the UI thread. Console and web apps have no UI thread, so execution continues on any available threadpool thread. `await` will restore the original *synchronization* context (eg variables) but won't try to restore the thread itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `TaskID` does matter to me because I'm trying to understand why it's null. I understand completely what you are saying but I still don't understand why `Task.CurrentId` is null after `await` is completed and Control is returned to the calling Task.

Answer (score 3):

There's two kinds of tasks. I call them Delegate tasks and Promise tasks.

Delegate tasks execute (synchronous) code; they're scheduled by a task scheduler onto a thread to run. Delegate tasks were the primary use case for `Task` before `async`/`await` came along, and several APIs (including `StartNew` and `CurrentId`) were designed for Delegate tasks and have surprising behavior when used with `async` code.

Promise tasks are the Future concept; they represent some operation that may complete in the future. Asynchronous tasks (such as are returned from `async` methods) are Promise tasks. Most tasks you encounter are Promise tasks. Promise tasks work with continuations, and while they *may* use task schedulers in some scenarios, they normally do not. The continuation of a Promise task may or may not have a `CurrentId` (and it usually won't).

Comment: My confusion now is that `Task.CurrentId` was not null on the first line of `SomeMethod` as the task (promise) started its execution. It only became `null` after `Task. Delay()`. Isn't the same `SomeMethod` task continue after `Task. Delay()`?

Comment: @RaoArman `async-await` is turned by compiler into state machine, where everything executed before first await is actually synchronous (i.e if you will put endless loop at start of `SomeMethod` you will never hit breakpoint after `var task = SomeMehod();`).

Comment: @RaoArman: Only Delegate tasks have `CurrentId` set. So the ID you're seeing is *not* the ID of the task returned from `SomeMethod` (you can verify this by checking the ID on the task returned from `SomeMethod`). It's the ID of just the first block of synchronous code. The rest of the blocks (the continuations) are run directly on the thread pool and are not wrapped in tasks, so there is no `CurrentId` for them.